# If isospin is conserved in a given strong interaction, can we say that the interaction is certainly allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, symmetry, strong-force, isospin-symmetry

If isospin is conserved in a given strong interaction, can we say that it is certainly allowed and it's not needed to check other conservation rules like baryon number, electric charge etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not!

Reactions preserving isospin, but violating P, C, B, are completely disallowed by the strong interactions.

Those violating Q or CPT, or Lorentz-Invariance, etc, are disallowed by all interactions (that we know of).

***Fine print*** . Actually, in real life strong interactions, isospin (and hence G) is an approximate symmetry, explicitly broken by a *very small amount*, $(m_d-m_u)/\Lambda_{QCD}$~1%, by virtue of the inequality of current quark masses. Such small effects can be monitored, but they are irrelevant to your rough-and-ready diagnostic use here.